# PDFTron Android Sample PDF

Tags: android, pdftron

Using the Android sample in the WebViewer folder I have an application in Android Studio which when run on my device works and displays the xod file given as expected. However I've tried to change the lines:

```
String documentPath = getFilesDir().getPath() + "/GettingStarted.xod";
InputStream in = getAssets().open("xod/GettingStarted.xod");
```

to

```
String documentPath = getFilesDir().getPath() + "/sample.pdf";
InputStream in = getAssets().open("xod/sample.pdf");
```

And have also changed the endsWith(".xod") to endsWith(".pdf") but I only get a grey screen. For this to work does the file have to be a .xod? As it works for xod files but not pdf files.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I've just also replaced android:pathPattern=".*\\.xod" to android:pathPattern=".*\\.pdf" and I now get the following error - "Uncaught Error: Error loading document: Error: Signature is wrong!" and the source file is pointing to CoreControls.js. Just thought id mention this update as it may help with resolving it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for mobile viewing you need to convert your files to the web-optimized XOD format.

The PDF backend for WebViewer is not available for mobile browsers. This is due to limitations of the hardware and the mobile browsers.

---

For desktop browsers, to switch from XOD backend to PDF backend, you need to follow the steps. See [here](https://www.pdftron.com/webviewer/demo/tutorials/getting-started.html) for more details, especially if you run into any errors.

```
var myWebViewer = new PDFTron.WebViewer({
    path: "lib",
    type: "html5",
    documentType: "pdf",
    initialDoc: "GettingStarted.pdf"
}, viewerElement);
```

Notice the documentType parameter is set to pdf.